# SELECT table value function into @temp_table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

Is there a way of selecting the results of a table value function into a table variable using MSSQL Server 2008?

Lets say I have a table value function that returns the following:

```
id | data
---------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
```

And I declare a table variable like so...

```
DECLARE @values TABLE(
  id int,
  data varchar(6)
)
```

Is it possible to SELECT INTO the @values table?  I can't seem to find the right syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
insert into @tablevar 
select columns from myTVF
```